# Yocto - Removing workspace directory from bblayers.conf gives me error

Tags: yocto

I created a Yocto layer `meta-application`:

```
meta-application
├── conf
│   ├── distro
│   │   └── our-distribution.conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── recipes-all
│   ├── application
│   │   └── application.bb
│   ├── image
│   │   └── image.bb
│   └── qtbase
│       └── qtbase_%.bbappend
└── recipes-kernel
    └── linux
        └── linux-ti-staging
            ├── 0001-apply-prerexisting-configuration.patch
            └── linux-ti-staging_%.bbappend
```

I want to start clean so I remove `tmp` subdirectory of my build folder.

I run `bitbake application` and it compiles fine.

```
WARNING: Host distribution "debian-11" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
Parsing recipes: 100% |#############################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:20
Parsing of 1950 .bb files complete (0 cached, 1950 parsed). 2800 targets, 300 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
NOTE: Multiple providers are available for runtime amx3-cm3 (amx3-cm3, amx3-cm3-phy)
Consider defining a PREFERRED_RPROVIDER entry to match amx3-cm3

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "debian-11"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "beaglebone"
DISTRO               = "pistam"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "1.0.0"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta
meta-poky
meta-yocto-bsp       = "dunfell:d2f1a20a19a8a1d604e703d630421a2cdbe65e14"
meta-qt5             = "dunfell:b4d24d70aca75791902df5cd59a4f4a54aa4a125"
meta-oe              = "dunfell:814eec96c2a29172da57a425a3609f8b6fcc6afe"
meta-application     = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
meta-ti              = "dunfell:80b79863c3c1f6a1e0aaff884ab5cb23e7e142c7"
meta-arm
meta-arm-toolchain   = "dunfell:ce535dfb96de4d2529f091d7d85a7172c626001c"
meta-phytec          = "dunfell:5650638aab1d69033c36c9f93d469b2f57737d16"
workspace            = "<unknown>:<unknown>"

WARNING: Unable to get checksum for application SRC_URI entry oe-logs: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ziga/yocto/sources-application/oe-logs'                                          | ETA:  0:00:00
WARNING: Unable to get checksum for application SRC_URI entry oe-workdir: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ziga/yocto/sources-application/oe-workdir'
WARNING: Unable to get checksum for application SRC_URI entry oe-logs: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ziga/yocto/sources-application/oe-logs'
WARNING: Unable to get checksum for application SRC_URI entry oe-workdir: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ziga/yocto/sources-application/oe-workdir'
Initialising tasks: 100% |##########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Sstate summary: Wanted 873 Found 872 Missed 1 Current 0 (99% match, 0% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
NOTE: application: compiling from external source tree /home/ziga/yocto/sources-application
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2680 tasks of which 2665 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.

Summary: There were 5 WARNING messages shown.
```

This is the recipe `application.bb` that was just build:

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

SRC_URI = "file:///home/ziga/yocto/sources-application"

DEPENDS = "qtbase boost qwt-qt5"
inherit qmake5
```

But unfortunately my `conf/bblayers.conf` looks like this:

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/ziga/yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/ziga/yocto/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/ziga/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/ziga/yocto/meta-qt5 \
  /home/ziga/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/ziga/yocto/meta-application \
  /home/ziga/yocto/meta-ti \
  /home/ziga/yocto/meta-arm/meta-arm \
  /home/ziga/yocto/meta-arm/meta-arm-toolchain \
  /home/ziga/yocto/meta-phytec \
  /home/ziga/yocto/build--beaglbone_black_c2/workspace \
  "
```

I don't like that directory `/home/ziga/yocto/build--beaglbone_black_c2/workspace` is also included!

This line is probably a leftover from when I edited the application with `devtool edit-recipe application` but I never finalized it. I just manually copied the edited recipe to it's current spot in my layer.

If I (a) remove this line, (b) remove `tmp` subdirectory of the build directory and (c) rebuild recipe with `bitbake application` I get an error:

```
WARNING: Host distribution "debian-11" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
Parsing recipes: 100% |#############################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:20
Parsing of 1949 .bb files complete (0 cached, 1949 parsed). 2799 targets, 300 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
NOTE: Multiple providers are available for runtime amx3-cm3 (amx3-cm3, amx3-cm3-phy)
Consider defining a PREFERRED_RPROVIDER entry to match amx3-cm3

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "debian-11"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "beaglebone"
DISTRO               = "pistam"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "1.0.0"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta
meta-poky
meta-yocto-bsp       = "dunfell:d2f1a20a19a8a1d604e703d630421a2cdbe65e14"
meta-qt5             = "dunfell:b4d24d70aca75791902df5cd59a4f4a54aa4a125"
meta-oe              = "dunfell:814eec96c2a29172da57a425a3609f8b6fcc6afe"
meta-application     = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
meta-ti              = "dunfell:80b79863c3c1f6a1e0aaff884ab5cb23e7e142c7"
meta-arm
meta-arm-toolchain   = "dunfell:ce535dfb96de4d2529f091d7d85a7172c626001c"
meta-phytec          = "dunfell:5650638aab1d69033c36c9f93d469b2f57737d16"

WARNING: Unable to get checksum for application SRC_URI entry oe-logs: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ziga/yocto/sources-application/oe-logs'                                          | ETA:  0:00:00
WARNING: Unable to get checksum for application SRC_URI entry oe-workdir: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ziga/yocto/sources-application/oe-workdir'
Initialising tasks: 100% |##########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Sstate summary: Wanted 880 Found 874 Missed 6 Current 0 (99% match, 0% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: application-1.0-r0 do_configure: Execution of '/home/ziga/yocto/build--beaglbone_black_c2/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/application/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.3068098' failed with exit code 2
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/ziga/yocto/build--beaglbone_black_c2/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/application/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.3068098
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function qmake5_base_preconfigure
| DEBUG: Shell function qmake5_base_preconfigure finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| ls: cannot access '/home/ziga/yocto/build--beaglbone_black_c2/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/application/1.0-r0/application-1.0/*.pro': No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Execution of '/home/ziga/yocto/build--beaglbone_black_c2/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/application/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.3068098' failed with exit code 2
ERROR: Task (/home/ziga/yocto/meta-application/recipes-all/application/application.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2673 tasks of which 2667 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/ziga/yocto/meta-application/recipes-all/application/application.bb:do_configure
Summary: There were 3 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

What is wrong? How can I remove `/home/ziga/yocto/build--beaglbone_black_c2/workspace` from `bblayers.conf`?

Comment: There's an issue with your `application.bb` recipe. Can you post the source code? Also, have you tried running `bitbake -c cleanall application` to clear out any broken build directories caused by copy/pasting the devtool/workspace recipe into your main source?

Comment: @Justin I added recipe sources.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand how your code is arranged. The recipe you've added is for a kernel, not `application.bb`. You also have some build warnings about force builds. Can you delete your `tmp` and `sstate-cache` directories, run the build again and re-post your code/errors above if they still occur.

Comment: @Justin Sorry! I posted the wrong recipe... Now it is correct. I also cleaned up the question a lot. Please take a look again.

Comment: It looks like sources are not copied from their folder to the directory set with `S` variable which is not set.

Comment: I think its wrong to provide a directory to `SRC_URI` with `file://` prefix. You can try to make a tarball from you sources and list it within `SRC_URI`

Comment: `file://` is a valid fetcher ([source](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-fetching.html#local-file-fetcher-file)).

Comment: I did not deny that `file://` is a valid fetcher but I doubt it properly works when providing a whole directory (which might also have subfolders). Therefore I suggested to make a tarball from your sources and provide something like `file:///home/ziga/yocto/sources-application/everything_needed.tar.gz`

Comment: Official documentation also specifies an exxample where `SRC_URI` is a folder. So it ought to work. I will test your suggestion and report back.

Comment: You should probably use the externalsrc class for using a source directory that's external to your Yocto layers. See: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/common-tasks.html?highlight=externalsrc#building-software-from-an-external-source

Comment: @Justin I followed this link and now the compilation finished. No problems! So this is the method to use with "closed source software" which is not published anywhere.